# MYSQL - How can I select a value from either table 1 or table 2?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
tbl1:
id
userid
subscriptionid
column2
column3

tbl2:
id
userid
subscriptionid
column4
column5
Column6
Column7
```

The subscriptionid values are unique, and would only exist in tbl1 or tbl2, but may also be null

I need a query to find a subscriptionid in either tbl1 or tbl2

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE (tbl1.subscriptionid OR tbl2.subscriptionid) = 'some_val';
```

Comment: Do `tbl1` and `tbl2` have the same schema definitions? Do they *really* only have one column each?

Comment: No, they do not have the same schema, and have multiple columns. I updated the post - Thanks

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: I tried several queries using UNION's and cannot get it right, but I am sure you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just normalize the `SELECT` list between the two queries in the `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT id, userid, subscriptionid, column2, column3, NULL AS column4, NULL AS column5, NULL AS column6, NULL AS column7
FROM tbl1 WHERE subscriptionid = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT id, userid, subscriptionid, NULL AS column2, NULL AS column3, column4, column5, column6, column7
FROM tbl2 WHERE subscriptionid = ?
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aQXg7bcI).

Comment: Beat me to my edit! OP should consider normalizing these two tables in their overall database design for better performance and scalability in the long-term. Short of that, adding indexes on both tables’ `subscriptionid` columns may help as well.

Comment: Agreed (there is a slight whiff), but the uniqueness of `subscriptionid` across these two tables suggests some kind of typing. Perhaps the `subscriptionid` should be PK in both tables and `userid` should exist only in `subs` table, but without knowing more about OP's db it is impossible to be sure.

Comment: Never seen db fiddle before
Will mess with that from now on

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using the SQL UNION operator to combine the results from both tables and then filter for the specific value you're looking for. Here's how you can write the query:

```
SELECT subscriptionid FROM tbl1 WHERE subscriptionid = 'some_val'
UNION
SELECT subscriptionid FROM tbl2 WHERE subscriptionid = 'some_val';
```

This query will return a result set that includes the subscriptionid values from either tbl1 or tbl2 where the subscriptionid matches the specified value 'some_val'. The UNION operator ensures that duplicate values are removed from the result set, and you'll get a unique list of matching subscriptionid values from both tables.

I hope this solves your problem..

Comment: This returns just the word subscriptionid